# How to filter single field in a view

Tags: views, entities

I am running Drupal 7 with the latest version of the Views module.

I have a content type called "School," which has an entity reference field for "classroom." The "classroom" content type has a radio button field for whether it has an assigned teacher.

I'd like my view to output a table which will list the total number of classrooms in each school (so school name in the first column, # of classrooms in the second column). After some messing around, I was able to get this working.

However, now I'd like to add a third column where I display the # of classrooms which have an assigned teacher. So if the classroom doesn't have a teacher assigned, it doesn't get included in the count. Anyone know how to accomplish this? It doesn't look like I can filter on individual fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were an SQL query your new column could be a subquery. I mean this new value of **# of classrooms with assigned teachers** has its own business logic, seperate from the list of data your already returning.

You can accomplish this using [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view). This lets you embed a view result -- per row of your existing view. From the project page:

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.
>
> It's highly recommended to use this module in conjunction with views
>   caching. [Views Content cache](http://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) and [Cache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions) are good ways of
>   caching views.

So:

1. Make a new view; called for instance with the human name of "sum rooms assigned teachers" (the machine name will be sum_rooms_assigned_teachers).
2. For this View simply use display mode of Show Fields; and include like the NID as a field; Under advanced settings enable Aggregation for the View. For the NID value use the `Count` aggregation.
3. Add a contextual filter to this view based on the school name.
4. Save your view.

Then in your parent view:

1. After installing Views Field View. Add a new Field your view of `Global: View`.
2. select the view named `sum_rooms_assigned_teachers`. Provide the contextual filter to the view of your school name or ID; it will look like `[!field_school_entityreference_id]` or something similiar.
3. Give this field whatever label you want.

Your main view should now show a room count. In the helper view you may want to deny access to anyone but the Administrator or other role -- as this is simply a helper view for this other view; and rather useless by itself.

Comment: this works, but if there are no classrooms with a teacher assigned, nothing shows up. Any way to output a 0?